# Linq return null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm having an issue about `Linq`. I have a form with all the fields required (Holiday) and another model (Profile), again with all fields required.

I am trying to cut off from a holiday request form some of the Holiday properties, that will be filled automatically with some of the Profile properties from database.

```
[Table("AspNetHoliday1")]
public class HolidayViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string TeamLeaderName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 21)]
    public int DaysOff { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string TLEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Flag { get; set; }       

}
```

And this is my Profile model:

```
[Table("AspNetProfile1")]
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Mark { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(13)]
    public string CNP { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Team { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string TeamLeaderEmail { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamLeaderName, htmlAttributes: new { 
@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TeamLeaderName, new { 
htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamLeaderName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DaysOff, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaysOff, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DaysOff, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in the `Holiday Controller` to do this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,TeamLeaderName,StartDate,EndDate,DaysOff,TLEmail,Flag")] HolidayViewModel holidayViewModel)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var firstName = (from b in db.ProfileViewModel
                             where b.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)
                             select b.FirstName).Single();
            holidayViewModel.FirstName = firstName;
            var lastName = (from b in db.ProfileViewModel
                            where b.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)
                            select b.LastName).Single();
            holidayViewModel.LastName = lastName;
            var email = (from b in db.ProfileViewModel
                         where b.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)
                         select b.Email).Single();
            holidayViewModel.Email = email;
            var tlEmail = (from b in db.ProfileViewModel
                           where b.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)
                           select b.TeamLeaderEmail).Single();
            holidayViewModel.TLEmail = tlEmail;

            holidayViewModel.Flag = false;

            holidayViewModel.TeamLeaderName = Request.Form["TeamLeaderName"];
            holidayViewModel.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["StartDate"]);
            holidayViewModel.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["EndDate"]);
            holidayViewModel.DaysOff = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["DaysOff"]);
            db.AspNetHolidays.Add(holidayViewModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessHoliday", "Success");
        }

        return View(holidayViewModel);
    }
```

Somehow, all the vars are returning null even if they should return a value since the values exist in the table Profile.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I have an error coming from `Sysem.Web.Mvc.ModelError, ErrorMessage: "The FirstName field is required" and its value is set to null.`

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Are you getting an error?  It would be better to provide the specific issue with a small sample and not all the code you are working with.

Comment: Hello, I tried debugging. I put a breakpoint in the if statement ant also for each var in the controller. It give me the error: ModelState.IsValid = false

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem? The wall of code you provided is hard to read through. And that error message should be edited into the question.

Comment: Moreover, it gives me another error: System.Web.Mvc.ModelError, ErrorMessage: "The FirstName field is required" and implicitly, its value is null.

Comment: This must mean the request model passed in from the browser does not match 100% the expected C# Model object.  Verify the request properties all match exactly and the model is serialize.

Comment: Can you try without the anti-forgery token? Not sure if you are adding it in the view.

Comment: Also, I don't see an editor for FirstName property in the view, therefore, it will indeed be null!

Comment: @RicardoPeres, my point is to cut off the field First Name in the form in order to populate this attribute in the Holiday Table with the information I have from the User's Profile Table, using the Holiday Controller.

Comment: In that case, why is the FirstName property marked with the [Required] attribute?

Comment: @RicardoPeres, even if I remove the [Required] Annotation, I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid is returning false because the model you're passing into the action has blank values for FirstName, LastName, etc. but they are marked as required.

Create a separate view model that only contains the properties you want to include in the form, then map those values to HolidayViewModel in the post action.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Where are you suggesting that the OP should add this line? How will this solve the problem? Can you add some more detail and explanation to your answer?

Comment: This is not the problem, Single() would throw an exception if the result was null.